# Protractor browser instances limit

Tags: protractor

I wondering if anyone know if there is any limit on number of browser instances you can start? 
When trying to use 8 chrome instances our test suite starts to get really flaky. We can see that the test execution for each test case is increasing drastically for some reason.
We don't have any test case dependency so it is not related to that.

Lowering the number of instances to 2-3 solves the problem.
But since we have lots of test cases we want to run as many instances as possible to get faster feedback. With only 2-3 instances the test suite takes over 1 hour.

Anyone else had these problems?

Using protractor 5.4.1, chromedriver 2.44, Chrome 69. 16 gb memory on the machine.

```
capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--headless', '--window-size=1280,1024']
        },
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 8
```

br
Ola

Comment: I have found that more than 4 on my machine will start to become flaky. This will change depending on your computer. The solution to this is to setup a dedicated testing server which is not always practical depending on your use case

Comment: Ok, thanx for the response. Then I know it is not only me that has this behavior.